# How to fix the migration error [Exception] Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

How to fix the migration error How to fix the migration error `[Exception]
Warning: PDOStatement::execute():` MySQL server has gone away in

```
C:\xampp7.0\htdocs\magento220\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\Adapter\Mysql.php on line 169.
```

I don't know how to find out this error? Could you please help me?

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera, could you please help me?

Comment: Please post the complete content of your Mysql.php content so we can see what is on your line 169.

Comment: If you have resolved this situation, please let us know how.  if the Answer helped, please Upvote/Accept to credit vmp for sharing his knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of possible reasons for this.

1. The database user account used or the table name is incorrect.
2. the user account used does not have the correct privileges to execute the queries. (Read for the source database and read/write for the destination database)
3. The source and destination database must be on the same SQL server.

read this for more information:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html